# How to write a mobile phone calculator gui with qt/qml

Tags: qml

[image]

Could anyone give me an example of qt/qml implementation of the above mobile phone calculator UI?

I am new to qt and qml, I've been fighting with grid alignment, auto element sizing, font, color, etc., and it's really frustrating...

Screen size is 960*540.  The two chinese characters in the UI means "Clear".

Answer (score 0):

Here are several calculator examples in QML:

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-declarative-calculator.html
- http://wiki.maemo.org/QML-EnhancedCalcExample